# Apache virtual host without domain name

Tags: php, apache, dns, virtualhost

I have a VPS with apache2 installed and I would like to access some PHP projects without a domain name just with the IP address. For example:

```
http://162.243.93.216/projecta/index.php
http://162.243.93.216/projectb/index.php
```

I have other projects with domain like example.com, in my directory /var/www/

```
/html/
   info.php
/projecta/
/projectb/
/example/
```

When I go to

```
http://162.243.93.216/info.php then /var/www/html/info.php is opened.
```

My file **000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
" http://162.243.93.216/info.php then /var/www/html/info.php is opened "
```

I am assuming this already works (If not, uncomment the `ServerAlias` line shown in the conf below)

You now want to map

`http://162.243.93.216/projecta/` to `/var/www/projecta`
`http://162.243.93.216/projectb/` to `/var/www/projectb`

For this you need to use the Apache **`Alias`** directive.

#### Update your `000-default.conf` file to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ServerAlias 162.243.93.216
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /projecta /var/www/projecta
    Alias /projectb /var/www/projectb

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: this is working for me but it seems the routing method is not. It is receiving correctly the ('/') request, but it gives back 404 file not found (not the laravel one) if you call to another route like "/something/"

Comment: Works fine. thnx

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked perfectly on  an Azure VM Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: @GabAntonelli for all who have the same issue: you just need to restart the Apache server, then it works just fine. Had the same problem and solved it like this.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new virtual host file, and setup like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerAlias 192.168.1.1 
        DocumentRoot /somewhere/public_html
        <Directory /somewhere/public_html/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
         AllowOverride Authconfig FileInfo
         Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

add the serveralias and it will recognize the IP address as well ...
if you want to add more IP addresses (like local network second interface), you can add more serveralias lines ...

Comment: but where I indicate that the URL is 162.243.93.216/projecta ... and i supose i need to add DocumentRoot /var/www/projecta ?

Comment: Documentroot is always the _root_ of the virtual server, if you put there a directory, you will be able to access it by the directory name ...
Aliasing basically does the same thing, without the need to phisically present the directories in the given place ...

So if your documentroot is /var/www/html/ and you can access it in http://162.243.93.216/ then a directory /var/www/html/projecta/ will be accessible via http://162.243.93.216/projecta/

Please don't forget that if you modify the 00_default vhost, every request with "unknnown" target domain name will be accessing your projects!

Comment: This is why i suggest you to setup your own virtual host for the IP address access ...

Answer (score 0):

Step Six — Set Up Local Hosts File (Optional)
If you have been using example domains instead of actual domains to test this procedure, you can still test the functionality of your virtual hosts by temporarily modifying the hosts file on your "LOCAL COMPUTER". This will intercept any requests for the domains that you configured and point them to your VPS server, just as the DNS system would do if you were using registered domains. This will only work from "YOUR COMPUTER", though, and is simply useful for testing purposes.

Note: Make sure that you are operating on your local computer for these steps and not your VPS server. You will need access to the administrative credentials for that computer.

If you are on a Mac or Linux computer, edit your local hosts file with administrative privileges by typing:

sudo vi /etc/hosts
If you are on a Windows machine, you can find instructions on altering your hosts file here.

The details that you need to add are the public IP address of your VPS followed by the domain that you want to use to reach that VPS:

127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   guest-desktop
server_ip_address example.com
server_ip_address example2.com

reference:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7?utm_source=Customerio&utm_medium=Email_Internal&utm_campaign=Email_CentOSDistroNginxWelcome&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTnpWbU5tUTJPV1F5TVRBMyIsInQiOiJhd0JCQVI0NDd0ZWprUDFaaDlhbENcL0lyTjdSbnhwMEpkTE1QcXJTcHl1ZXFhNURKVmVBZHFKMk92RW1kSFwvMHowOW0zcExhaUdyOU42U2lLbk1Cd2FRYzB4XC9lbkhlWnd1ekZOcW1sZVhRYlwvT0xrTUpmQ2dEK2dNVUw4alFrc00ifQ%3D%3D