# Laravel access api without domain in virtual hosts

Tags: apache, laravel, virtualhost

I ve got a laravel app all set up and working when my virtual host is set as follows :

```
ServerName mylaravelproj.com

<Directory /var/www/mylaravelproj/public>
..rules here
```

So all i need to do is access mylaravelproj.com/api/whateverRouteHere

However, i wouldnt know how to access the api without a domain name as

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mylaravelproj/public

<Directory /var/www/mylaravelproj/public>
..rules here
```

doesnt work when accessing 192.168.xxx.xxx/mylaravelproj/public/api/whateverRouteHere

Im quite new to configuring apache and a little confused as to why this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is listening for the domain `mylaravelproj.com`, then why don't you add an entry to your `hosts` file like this:

```
192.168.xxx.xxx    mylaravelproj.com
```

And then flush your DNS cache and then visit http://mylaravelproj.com and you should be able to access your app.

---

On windows, this is how I usually setup laravel apps. I use XAMPP, so I add the following entry to: **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mylaravelproj.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mylaravelproj/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

and then get my LAN ip in windows using **ipconfig /all** in Command Prompt (say my LAN ip is `192.168.1.122`) and then set it on the hosts file: **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
192.168.1.122    mylaravelproj.com
```

then in Command Prompt, flush the DNS Cache using **ipconfig /flushdns**

*Note* it's not good idea to run your dev env using full domain, you should use something like mylaravelproj.dev or mylaravelproj.local*

Comment: i cant add things to hosts as im trying to access it through mobile devices and going to each one of them and tampering with the hosts file would be tedious :/. Im serving the thing in a local network and i was wondering if it could be somehow done without a domain name

Comment: Then you need to look into Dynamic DNS (e.g. https://www.noip.com) or get yourself a cheap $5 DigitalOcean VPS and deploy your app online.

Comment: So essentially, there's no way other than somehow either through external hosting/host fliles or dyn dns to do it :/.

I just wonder why

mylaravelproj.com/api/whateverRouteHere works but
192.168.xxx.xxx/mylaravelproj/public/api/whateverRouteHere doesnt. I mean the first one resolves pretty much  to the  same url.. right?

Comment: Do you get any errors? you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706846/apache-virtual-host-without-domain-name and then you can access your app api endpoint like this: `192.168.xxx.xxx/api/whateverRouteHere`

Comment: I get a 404 page not found even if i set 000-default to the root of the project. In that case the public Laravel page is served but the api is not working. So

http://192.168.1.34/api/test doesnt work while
http://whateverdomain/api/test works

This might be a laravel specific thing but it just doesnt make sense to me why one works and the other doesnt as they seem to be essnetially the same thing.

Worth noting that both plain http://192.168.1.34/ and http://whateverdomain/ display the same page found in the laravel public folder as expected so it must be an implementation detail...

Comment: if this works http://whateverdomain/api/test but this doesnt http://192.168.1.34/api/test, see what this `whateverdomain` is resolving to, do a ping/dig request on the domain

Comment: You can use "live preview" via npm (node), see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#browsersync-reloading. Last time I used it it worked on my local-network (same wifi router) without any trouble cross-platform.